# Stuck with the statement: $t^4+2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ gives rise to...

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic, irreducible-polynomials

This is from Ian Stewart's book on Galois theory, I am looking at irreducible polynomials.

It talks of irreducibility over mod. It takes as an example, $f(t)=t^4+15t^3+7$ over integers, and asks us to consider it over $\mathbb{Z}_5$ which makes it $t^4+2$. If this is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}_5$, then it either has a factor of degree 1, or a product of 2 factors of degree 2. This is fine, I understand.

What I don't understand is,  "The first possibility gives rise to an element $x \in \mathbb{Z}_5$, such that $x^4+2=0$"

Simply, why? Why does "having a factor of degree 1" imply this?
This first possibility is essentially, $(t+a)(t^3+bt^2+ct+d)=t^4+2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5$, yes? I tried expanding this and sought if any of the coefficients comparison leads to me concluding that there must be an element of $x^4+2=0$ in the field but no.

I don't see why this conclusion is obtained. Can someone explain to me in detail please?

Comment: Your conclusion about the impossibility of $x^4+2=0$, if correct, simply says that the hypothesis, "the first possibility" is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that the polynomial having a linear factor $t+a$ over $\mathbb{Z}_5$ implies, indeed is equivalent to, the polynomial having a root at $-a  \in \mathbb{Z}_5$. This is not specific to this polynomial but is general fact for polynomials over fields.

But to see it explicitly in your explicit factorization if you plug in $-a$ you get $0$ on the left as you have a factor of $(-a)+ a= 0$ and thus you have $0$ on the right so $(-a)^4 + 2 = 0$, so $-a$ is the $x$ you seek.

Thus if $t^4 + 2$ had a linear factor, there would be a root $x \in \mathbb{Z}_5$, that is some $x$ such that $x^4 + 2 = 0$.

This  is however impossible, as $x^4$ can only be $1$ or $0$ for $x \in \mathbb{Z}_5$. (This follows from little Fermat theorem, or by just checking all cases.)

Thus one can exclude the existence of a linear factor, and can focus on the only remaining case that $t^4 + 2$ is the product of two quadratic polynomials.

Comment: good lord, sorry that was a typo, I will fix now. And thank you for answering, so to check what you meant, the possibility of factoring with $t-a$ will give rise to $x$(or $a$ in my notation), such that $a^4+2=0$ which cannot be...but if I can factor in terms of $t^2$, it is not immediately clear if such an "impossible" element arises so we'll go with that.. yes?

Comment: Thanks for the clarififcation; I expanded the answer a bit. Yes, the assumption of a linear factor leads to a contradiction. So what rests is the case that it is a product of two quadratic polynomials, which then is further investigated.

Comment: Awesome, that made it clear now, thank you for taking the time to answer my question!